# Can people get in trouble for investigating or charging the president?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, president

Not word for word and please correct me.

Is there a law like this? If so:
 Should any criminal investigation or legal action, investigation even a phone call that takes time from the president in office in any criminal investigation can be interpreted and considered a violation of this stature "The US president cannot be prosecuted for any crime while in office"? Unless it is a political offense like espionage is it a crime to use taxpayer money to investigate the president?

Related: [Can the US president be charged of crime such as murder while in office?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17025)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the US president be charged of crime such as murder while in office?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17025/can-the-us-president-be-charged-of-crime-such-as-murder-while-in-office)

Comment: @Nij it is not the same and the answer is on point.

Comment: @Nij I think he is trying to ask if people can get in trouble for investigating or charging the president, not if the president can be charged.

Comment: @Putvi exactly.tks revised.

Comment: there is no such statute as  - a violation of this stature  {SIC] "The US president cannot be prosecuted for any crime while in office"?

Comment: Are you including congressional investigations in the scope of this question?

Comment: @phoog any criminal investigation

Comment: Congressional investigations are not criminal investigations.  Congress does not have the power to lay criminal charges against anyone, to prosecute anyone, or to try anyone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The policy of the Justice Department is that the President of the United States can not be indicted. https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-trump-russia-indictment-explainer/can-a-sitting-us-president-face-criminal-charges-idUSKCN1QF1D3

All federal prosecutors are part of the Justice Department and that means the guidelines for them say it is prohibited. There is not an actual law saying you can or can't indict the president. The idea is that impeachment is the right way to handle presidential wrongdoing, because the president shouldn't be distracted and he could be charged after leaving office or if he was impeached.

The president can be investigated though and some have. 
https://www.abc.net.au/news/2018-03-13/trump-nixon-five-times-the-fbi-went-up-against-the-president/9539192